# Bootstrap Datepicker not showing in date field

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datepicker

I came across an issue with a datepicker from Bootstrap. I am able to get it working on one page, with a modal that is called within that PHP file by doing

```
var date_input=$('input[name="date"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
      var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
      var options={
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        container: container,
        todayHighlight: true,
        autoclose: true,
      };
      date_input.datepicker(options);
```

I also have another popup which calls a separate php file and I'm trying to use the same method, but it doesn't seem to work. The code in the separate PHP file is

```
echo "Delivery Date: <input class='form-control date2' tabindex='3' id='date2' name='date2' value='$delivery_date' type='text'/> ";
```

And for the datepicker

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var date_input=$('input[name="date2"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
      var options={
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        todayHighlight: true,
        autoclose: true,
      };
      date_input.datepicker(options);
});
```

Why is it working in the first file, but not the second?

Comment: What do your console logs say in browser? (press f12)

Comment: Nothing. There are no errors or warnings.